# Duplicate objects are shown in request json after the request is sent to client

Tags: microservices

I have the model class which is getting generated by swagger which has a field `xTimestamp`:

```
public class HeaderVBO {
      
      
  @JsonProperty("xTimestamp")
  private List<HeaderVBOXTimestamp> xTimestamp = new ArrayList<HeaderVBOXTimestamp>();
```

Below code is setting `HeaderVBO` object:

```
HeaderVBO headerVBO = new HeaderVBO();
HeaderVBOXTimestamp headerVBOXtimestamp = new HeaderVBOXTimestamp();
headerVBOXtimestamp.setValue(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
headerVBOXtimestamp.setFormat("int64");
headerVBO.addXTimestampItem(headerVBOXtimestamp);
```

This object is set inside another parent object and send it client. When I saw the client request I see that there are 2 different arrays which same name are getting created:

```
"header": [{"xtimestamp": [{"value": "1626941626845","format": "int64"}],"xTimestamp": [{"value": "1626941626845","format": "int64"}]}],
```

In the above `xtimestamp` is additionally added. I searched in complete project but didn't find any variable with xtimestamp. I also debugged the code and there is no extra list is getting added as well.